# How to import a library in a script that is being called by another script in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have a python file called main.py which look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import numpy as np
import load
a = load.compute()
print(a)
```

The above file calls a module called load.py which looks like this:

```
def compute():
    import numpy as np
    a = np.array([2,3,1,0])
    return a
```

However, I get the error: NameError: name 'np' is not defined.

I have also tried to put `import numpy as np` as the first line of load.py before the compute() function, and still received the same error.

How can I import a library in a script that is being called by another Python script?

Comment: Your code seems correct. Are you sure these are the exact scripts causing the error?

Comment: no need to import numpy in first file. only import in which file you want to use it. so.. removing import numpy as np from first file should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import numpy in main.py,
but anyway: your code works. Check if files in same directory, try to call `python main.py` from that directory.

Answer (score -1):

The error you have mentioned is not reproducible. It works for me.